# EnhancedGrid within another EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I'm using the dojo grid cell formatter to display an inner grid within another grid.  Even though the inner grid is added, it does not display on the HTML page cause its height and width are 0px.

My JSP page and the JS page where the grids are created is shown below.  Any help will be appreciated.

My guess is that calling grid.startup() in the cell formatter is probably not the right place.  But where should I move the startup() call to -or- is there something else that needs to be done to get the inner grid to render correctly.

----JSP file ----

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> dojo.require("portlets.ListPortlet"); var <portlet:namespace/>args = { namespace: '<portlet:namespace/>', listDivId: 'listGrid' }; var <portlet:namespace/>controller = new portlets.ListPortlet(<portlet:namespace/>args);  dojo.addOnLoad(function(){ <portlet:namespace/>controller.init(); }); </script>        

</div>
```

----JS file ----

```
dojo.declare("portlets.ListPortlet", null, { 

        constructor: function(args){    
                dojo.mixin(this,args);  
                this.params = args; 
        }, 
        init: function(){ 

                var layout = [[         
                                {field: 'site', name: 'Site', width: '30px'  } 
                                {field: 'name', name: 'Full Name', width: '100px'},                             
                                {field: 'recordStatus', name: 'Status', width: '80px'  }                           
                        ],[ 
                                {field: '_item', name: ' ', filterable: false,  formatter: this.formatNotesTable, colSpan: 3  }                         
                        ]]; 



                this.grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({ 
                    autoHeight: true, 
                    autoWidth: true, 
                    selectable: true, 
                    query:{ 
                    fromDate: start, 
                        toDate: end 
                    },               
                    rowsPerPage: 10 
                }); 
                this.grid.placeAt(dojo.byId(this.listDivId)); 


                this.dataStore = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({target: dataURL, idAttribute: idAttribute}); 
                this.grid.setStructure(layout); 
                this.grid.startup(); 
        },           
        formatNotesTable(rowObj) { 

            var gridData = { 
                        identifier:"id", 
                        items: [ 
                                      {id:1, "Name":915,"IpAddress":6}, 
                                      {id:2, "Name":916,"IpAddress":7} 
                                ] 
            }; 


            var gridStructure =  [{ 
                        cells:[ 
                                    [ 
                                          { field: "Name", 
                                                name: "Name",                                         
                                          }, 
                                          { field: "IpAddress", 
                                                name: "Ip Address" ,                                         
                                                styles: 'text-align: right;' 
                                          } 
                                    ] 
                              ] 
                        }]; 

    var gridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( { data: gridData} ); 

    var cpane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane ({     
    content: "inner grid should be displayed below" 
     }); 


     var subgrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({ 
                        store: gridStore, 
                        structure: gridStructure, 
                        style: {width: "325px", height: "300px"}     
                    }); 

                subgrid.placeAt(cpane); 
            subgrid.startup(); 
            return cpane; 
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a dojox.layout.TableContainer inside the EnhancedGrid.